# form_for undefined method `model_name' for ::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, form-for

I have been having issues with form_for rendering. I want to have a _form.html.erb partial that deals with both the creation and editing of my Problem record. When I go down the route of using

```
<%= form_for(@problem) do |f| %>
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for Problem::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class
```

In my routes.rb I have the following:

```
PW::Application.routes.draw do
root to: 'problems#index', via: :get
resources :problems do
member do
  post 'up_vote'
  post 'down_vote'
 end
end
```

I also have this my in Problem Controller

```
class ProblemsController < ApplicationController
 include Concerns::Votes

 def new
  @problem = Problem.new
 end

 def index
 @problem = Problem.all
 end

 def show
 @problem = find_problem
 end

 def create
 @problem = current_user.problems.new(problem_params)
 @problem.save
 redirect_to @problem
 end


private

 def find_problem
 @problem = Problem.find(params[:id])
end

 def problem_params
params.require(:problem).permit(:name, :description, :url)
end
end
```

I can get it to work if I specify the following :

```
<%= form_for @problem.new, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
```

However I feel that this is repeating myself if I then have to make a separate partial just for the edit. I really cant work out why this doesn't want to work. Could it be I am rendering the form on index.html.erb?

Any help or direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a `Problem` model?

Comment: Please check you are inherit your Problem class with Active record.  it should be sub class of active record

Comment: could you please show your Problem class

Comment: Post your `controller`.

Comment: @RichPeck I have added it above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LOL why didn't I see this earlier?

> Could it be I am rendering the form on index.html.erb?

Yep, it's totally the problem. Reason is here:

```
Problem::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class
```

You're getting back a `relation` object (defines a collection, rather than single record). This is caused by this:

```
#controller
def index
   @problem = Problem.all
end
```

The error is beacuse `form_for` expects a single record. You need to use this in your controller & it will work:

```
#controller
def index
   @problem = Problem.new
   @problems = Problem.all
end

#view
<%= @problems.each do |problem| %>
    <%= problem.name %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @problem do |f| %>
```

Comment: So @rich-peck in my view for index.html.erb I am printing out all the records for Project and then i am also rendering the _form partial. Is there a way to have both on the page?

Comment: Sure! Just use a different variable like @jbmyid recommended. I'll update my anwer to show

Comment: @user1995600 You should be highlighted the rendering of `_form.html.erb `from the index page,not in the end of the story.

Comment: @pavan sorry I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: He basically meant the way you structured your question made it difficult to appreciate the form was being called from `index`, which is pretty big factor

Comment: @RichPeck Yes,it is pretty big factor considering the usual way of rendering forms.It is an unusual way.

Comment: @RichPeck Works great.

Comment: @pavan, of course. I originally thought the form was rendered in `new` action, which made it confusing

Comment: @RichPeck I see. The reasoning behind it was I didnt want to have the user to go to a separate page just to create a problem. Maybe I should create a dashboard controller that deals with it instead of the index action.

Comment: You can use a partial, just pass the object through the `locals` argument

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `create` method defined in your controller like this

```
def create
 @problem = Problem.new

 #other logic goes here
end
```

And your `form_for` for `create` action should be like this

```
<%= form_for @problem, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
```

Comment: @downvoter Could you please explain the reason behind downvote?

Comment: Not sure who downvoted, however woudnt this mean I would have two forms. One for new and one for edit? I pasted my controller code above.

Comment: @user1995600 Yes,you should have two `forms` for each `create` and `edit`.And you can render a partial `_form.html.erb` in both forms.

Comment: @user1995600 Try this `@problem = Problem.new(problem_params)` in the new and create methods.

Comment: Hey @pavan no luck on the problem = Problem.new(problem_params) it gives me param is missing or the value is empty: problem. I am not convinced by the other solution for have two separate form_for's. I think the issue is me calling the _form.html.erb partial from the index action.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using `@problems`, as you said the form is in index page. If you are doing so then the index action  code should be like

```
def index
  @problems = Problem.all
  @problem = Problem.new
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for form_for
```

It was for a simple reason:

I was using `form_for`, where I should have been using `form_with`. As soon as I changed that it worked as expected.